# JQuery unable to mouse over and click on floating menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://www.verizonwireless.com/homepage/  please make sure to have / at end of homepage/ so ".com/homepage/"

I try to move the mouse over [Phones, Plans etc.] Menu and click on sub-menu items. I tried all my best it is not working. Please help.

```
$('.links-menu').find('a:visible:contains("Phones")').mouseover()
```

or click does not work.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Class Name try this one:

With Contains Phones

```
$('.o-tier-two a:contains("Phones")').mouseover();
```

By `nth-child`

```
$('.o-tier-two li:first').mouseover();
```

If you need click, just find the selector and click. Mouseover doesn't need in this case.

```
$('.o-tier-three a:contains("Smartphones")').closest('td').click();
```

If you are trying this for automation then better to use XPath instead of Executing JQuery

```
//div[contains(@class, 'o-tier-two')]//span[contains(text(), 'Phone')]//parent::a
```

Something Like This.

Comment: the above code is  on different version of our page.  make sure you have https://www.verizonwireless.com/homepage/  somehow / removed from homepage. so its .com/homepage/ so you will see a different flavor of the page